# How fill area between lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy

```
%matplotlib inline
import sympy as sy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = sy.Symbol('x')

y1 = pow(x, 3)
y2 = 1/x

p1 = sy.plot(y1, (x, -3, 3), ylim=[-2,2], show=False)
p2 = sy.plot(y2, (x, 0, 3), ylim=[-2,2], show=False)
p3 = sy.plot_implicit(sy.Eq(x, 2), show=False)

p1.append(p2[0])
p1.append(p3[0])
p1[0].line_color = 'red'
p1[1].line_color = 'green'
p1[2].line_color = 'black'
p1.size=(10, 10)
p1.show()
```

[image]

Hi all!
Need fill area between all 3 lines.
I have no idea how do that, in docs

"fill : dict, optional
A dictionary specifying the type of color filling required in the plot. The keys in the dictionary should be equivalent to the arguments of the matplotlib’s fill_between() function."

But like fill_between don't work.
Please any example of p1.fill=(...)
link or answer. anything

Comment: What exactly is your expected output? Also, present the minimal code to reproduce the issue you have? It would also help to demonstrate the effort of what you tried and failed?

Answer (score 0):

You have to determine x range yourself, otherwise it works straight out of the box

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xx = np.arange(1, 2, 0.01)
yy1 = x**3
yy2 = 1/x

plt.fill_between(xx, yy1, yy2)
plt.show()
```

More info: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html
Check out also: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/index.html

Comment: need to fill on classical math axes. and it dont work for sympy.fill like plt.fill_between, or I dont understand something)

TypeError: fill_between() argument after ** must be a mapping, not tuple

Comment: Try use definition of xx, yy1 and yy2 from above and `p2 = sy.plot(y2, (x, 0, 3), fill={"x": xx, "y1": yy1, "y2": yy2}, ylim=[-2,2], show=False)`